# cURL keeps running instead of stopping after one request

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I have a PHP function that interacts with an API via a cURL request. The problem is, once its called it keeps running forever, requesting the same stuff again and again, instead of just making 1 request. It made like a thousand of the same calls in just a few seconds.

I'm pretty new to curl - could you tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
function zapier_send_br($data){

        // Create a new cURL resource
        $ch = curl_init(ZAPIER_BR_URL);
        
        // Set up request data to send json via POST
        $fields = array(
            'pp_br' => array(
                'token'   => 'xxx',
                'data'   => $data
            )
        );
    
        $payload = json_encode($fields);
    
        // Attach encoded JSON string to the POST fields
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
    
        // Set the content type to application/json
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
    
        // Return response instead of outputting
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    
        // Execute the POST request
        $result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
    
        // Close cURL resource
        curl_close($ch);
    
        return $result;

}
```

How can I make it so it only runs once (or until a single successful request)?

The functions runs in a foreach loop, but the loop itself only runs 1-2 times, tested and logged it.

I have other cURL requests as well on the same page (all behave the same loopy way) - should I perhaps use curl_reset($ch) to make sure they don't interfere with each other?

Comment: this code does not seems to have problem, is it maybe inserted in a for loop?

Comment: It is inserted in a foreach loop, but the foreach only runs 1-2 times...Tested it multiple times.  
I have other cURL requests as well on the same page (all behave the same loopy way) - should I perhaps use curl_reset($ch) to make sure they don't interfere with each other?

Comment: this should not be a problem, since you instantiate a new connection for each method..

Comment: Agreed, this function should not re-issue requests. Can you share the code where you call the `zapier_send_br` function?